# Return copy of a DataFrame that contains only rows with missing data in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am looking for the opposite of the `dropmissing` function in DataFrames.jl so that the user knows where to look to fix their bad data. It seems like this should be easy, but the `filter` function expects a column to be specified and I cannot get it to iterate over all columns.

```
julia> df=DataFrame(a=[1, missing, 3], b=[4, 5, missing])
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a       │ b       │
│     │ Int64?  │ Int64?  │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 1       │ 4       │
│ 2   │ missing │ 5       │
│ 3   │ 3       │ missing │

julia> filter(x -> ismissing(eachcol(x)), df)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching eachcol(::DataFrameRow{DataFrame,DataFrames.Index})

julia> filter(x -> ismissing.(x), df)
ERROR: ArgumentError: broadcasting over `DataFrameRow`s is reserved
```

I am basically trying to recreate the `disallowmissing` function, but with a more useful error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(a=[1, missing, 3], b=[4, 5, missing])
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a       │ b       │
│     │ Int64?  │ Int64?  │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 1       │ 4       │
│ 2   │ missing │ 5       │
│ 3   │ 3       │ missing │

julia> df[.!completecases(df), :] # this will be faster
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a       │ b       │
│     │ Int64?  │ Int64?  │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ missing │ 5       │
│ 2   │ 3       │ missing │

julia> @view df[.!completecases(df), :]
2×2 SubDataFrame
│ Row │ a       │ b       │
│     │ Int64?  │ Int64?  │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ missing │ 5       │
│ 2   │ 3       │ missing │

julia> filter(row -> any(ismissing, row), df)
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a       │ b       │
│     │ Int64?  │ Int64?  │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ missing │ 5       │
│ 2   │ 3       │ missing │

julia> filter(row -> any(ismissing, row), df, view=true) # requires DataFrames.jl 0.22
2×2 SubDataFrame
 Row │ a        b
     │ Int64?   Int64?
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │ missing        5
   2 │       3  missing
```

Comment: Is there a faster method if I don't need a copy? I realized I can probably just view a slice of the original DataFrame since I am going to error out anyway.

Comment: For `filter` pass `view=true` kwarg in a version that will be released next week (you can also safely use master; the only thing that blocks the release is some minor printing tweak). For `completecases` solution just put `@view` in front of the whole expression.